# aspell-python installation error

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, aspell

I am trying to install **aspell-python package** for spell correction. 
**Facing problem** while installing the package.

Error :

```
python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'aspell' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c aspell.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/aspell.o
aspell.c:53:20: fatal error: aspell.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

**GCC** is already install version **gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2**

**libaspell15** is already install

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Need to install **sudo apt-get install libaspell-dev**

Comment: @SSA, I might be wrong but I think Nikkz has just answered their own question. In which case it is valid.

Comment: Facing the same issue. This didn't solve my problem.